# How do I update field with the id appended to a string on creation in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I have the following table and a corresponding model:

```
Orders
ID|ORDER_REF|....
```

The order ref is of the format 'ORDER#000-00'+ORDER.ID The thing is that I need to enable it such that the order ref is set on insertion. Is there a way to do this without having to do an update after the insertion, I'm using RoR here.

Comment: Are you using a form to perform an Insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need that data in your database? The best way would be to just have a method on your model that returns the order ref in the desired format, based on the `id` in the database.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  def order_ref
    "ORDER#000-#{self.id.to_s.rjust(3, '0')}"
  end
end
```

With the abobe you can do this:

```
order = Order.create(params[:order])
order.id #=> 12
order.order_ref #=> "ORDER#000-012"
```

If you *do* need the order ref in the database, I recommend using an `after_create` callback:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :generate_order_ref

  def generate_order_ref
    self.order_ref = "ORDER#000-#{self.id.to_s.rjust(3, '0')}"
    save
  end
end
```

This *does* do an update after inserting, but I don't see any problem with that.